# Anyone have a workaround to bug with save and send with outlook add in?

Tags: excel, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm not sure if this can be fixed programatically but I'm having the following issue with an outlook addin. To reproduce:

```
1) Create a new Outlook add in
2) Add a ribbon to the solution
3) Set the RibbonType to Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose
4) Run the solution
5) Open a workbook in Excel
6) Click File > Save and Send > Send as Attachment > Then send or close the mail
7) Click file Save As - The dialog box appears behind the excel window.
```

After the send as attachment window is closed you cant access any dialog boxes in excel.

Does anyone have a fix or meaningful workaround for this bug?

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: have you tried with 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False' ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the culprit is Microsoft's Ribbon Designer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhruvkh/archive/2012/05/14/outlook-ribbon-woes-on-performing-send-as-e-mail-via-other-office-2010-apps.aspx

However, caveat emptor: I'm seeing the same problem with an Outlook add-in that I created, which uses RibbonXML directly (I hadn't even heard of the Ribbon Designer until yesterday) so I'm currently trying to find out more about what exactly the underlying problem is.